# Symfony2 bin/vendors

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.0

When i try to run the following command from my Symfony2 project root

```
php bin/vendors install
```

I get the following error:

> Could not open input file: bin/vendors

I'm completely new to git and composer and I can't find a way to get this working
I wanted to install Doctrine Fixtures Bundle as described in the manual: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AFAIK, the newest versions of Symfony2 don't use bin/vendors anymore. Instead they use Composer, which means you might be looking at the 2.0 doc instead of the 2.1.

try adding the following to your composer.json file.

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

then run

```
$ php composer.phar update
```

Comment: Also, if you're new to Composer, you will have to find the package names from [Packagist](http://packagist.org) for bundles you wish to install in your project.

Comment: Great, this was my first stackoverflow answer, glad I didn't steer ya wrong =p

Comment: @Duncan: where is composer.json file. I can't find in Symfony dir inside windows 7 wamp